# Kik bot will not reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, portforwarding, kik

I have a Kik bot that I am hosting on my computer. I setup the configureation with the following code:

```
let request = require('request')

request.post('https://api.kik.com/v1/config',
             {
             "auth":{
             "user":"bhs************",
             "pass":"*******-*****-*****-****"
             },
             "headers":{
             "User-Agent":"request"
             },
             "form":{
             "webhook":"https://(my public ip):8080",
             "features":{
             "manuallySendReadReceipts":false,
             "receiveReadReceipts":false,
             "receiveDeliveryReceipts":false,
             "receiveIsTyping":false
             }
             }
             });
```

And here is the code for my actual bot:

```
'use strict';

let util = require('util');
let https = require('https');
let Bot  = require('@kikinteractive/kik');

// Configure the bot API endpoint, details for your bot
let bot = new Bot({
                  username: 'bhs************',
                  apiKey: '*******-*****-*****-****',
                  baseUrl: 'https://(my public ip):8080'
                  });

bot.updateBotConfiguration();

bot.onTextMessage((message) => {
                  console.log("New Message")
                  message.reply(message.body);
                  });

// Set up your server and start listening
let server = https
.createServer(bot.incoming())
.listen(8080);
console.log("Server Running on port 8080")
```

I have setup port forwarding on my router to redirect to my computer with the internal and external port of 8080. I also have the protocol set to both TCP and UDP. Here is a photo if that setup:

[image: Kik Bot port forwarding]
My bot has stopped telling me that I need to Finnish setting it up every time I text it, but now it never says anything. Is there something that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like its not hitting your endpoint properly. I would suggested using ngrok to give yourself a public URL and it will forward to your local IP.

https://ngrok.com/

Comment: It's a good temporary solution (I mean, what I was doing was too) but I don't like how I need a new public URL every time I start the server.